# How can I generate an attribute within Devise registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I've setup Devise for my Rails app, and I'm trying to generate a user id based off the first and last name.  I thought I would set up my Devise model (User) with the following to do this...

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :generate_user_code

  validates_presence_of :code
  validates :code, :length { is: 4 }, allow_blank: false

  private

    def generate_user_code
      # generate a special user id based off first and last name provided.
      self.code = "JDOE"
    end
end
```

**ApplicationController.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :code, :title) }
    end
end
```

With the above setup when I try to create a user through registration I get the two validation errors after submit.  I'm not sure why the `before_create` isn't executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't familiar with this method but appears instead of using `before_create` I needed to use `before_validation`.  I discovered the method at the documentation here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/activerecord_validations_callbacks.html

Thanks to anyone who took the time to look into my issue!